# Android app works when I run it from eclipse, but not when I run it from emulator home screen-->apps

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to build an Android app, and I am using eclipse. When I run the app from eclipse, the app will pop up and it works fine, but when I try to go back to home page on emulator and run the app from home button-->app-->my app, it says "launcher has stopped" and won't show anything on the screen.
Does anyone know what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a full log of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new emulator and check out, it might not loaded properly.